# SQLServer query using memory innefficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, insert, query-optimization

I've developed a insert statement in Sql Server. it utilizes several joins along with an inner select. It is causing problems in my database due to insufficient memory.

It also takes several minutes to run despite only inserting a few hundred rows. Does anyone have suggestions for how I can improve this query in order to allow it to run more efficiently without changing the end results? Thanks!

```
insert into This_Table 
select distinct *
from fv
join lv on lv.field1 = fv.field1
join sa on sa.field1 = fv.field2
where field3 + field2 not in (select distinct field3 + field2
from fv
join lv on lv.field1 = fv.field1
join This_Table T on fv.field2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + case 
when COMPONENT_PART COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like 'S%' or `COMPONENT_PART COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like 'T%' then STUFF(field3 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 1, 1, '') else COMPONENT_PART COLLATE     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS end like T.field4 + case when field5 like 'S%' or     field5 like 'T%' then STUFF(field5, 1, 1, '') else T.field5 end + '%')`
and SA.field6 <> 'EXPIRED'
order by field3
```

Comment: This is just my observation, change distinct > GROUP BY, change 'NOT IN' > to left joins, all 'WHERE' conditions use it at JOINs when you can ... if you toss your table schema and data example someone could probably help you out

Comment: An `ORDER BY` with an insert is superfluous, because data in a table is not ordered. A `DISTINCT` in a `NOT IN` clause is also superfluous and can cause the DBMS to do unnecessary work. Then how can there be duplicate records you need to remove with `DISTINCT`? It is `select *` from three tables; does one of it contain duplicate records? If so, why? If not so, why `DISTINCT`?

Comment: The fact that you join on column expressions (`fv.field2 + case when ... end like T.field4 + case when ... end`) rather than on mere columns, may very likely indicate a bad database model.

Comment: @Veljko89: No. (1.) `GROUP BY` is for data aggregation (`SUM`, `COUNT` etc.). If you only want distinct rows, use the straight-forward `DISTINCT`, so as to give the DBMS as little work as possible. (2.) The anti join pattern is a trick used on weak DBMS that don't know (yet) how to handle `[NOT] IN` / `[NOT] EXISTS` effectively. I doubt a current version of SQL Server to be that weak. (3.) Whether you have criteria on an inner join in `ON` or `WHERE` doesn't affect performance. It's merely a matter of readability. But yes, (4) table definitions and sample data would probably help :-)

Comment: You might find more help over on [SO's dba site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).  When asking about query performance it always helps if you include the execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The give-away here is that you have a `DISTINCT` in your query. There is no way for me to know from the info you've given if it applies here but in 99% of the cases I've seen a DISTINCT it's being used to 'fix' incomplete `JOIN`s.

Some other notes:

- add aliases, especially when you use the same table multiple times in the same query; this makes things much more readable
- you can use `LIKE '[AB]%'` instead of `LIKE 'A%' OR LIKE 'B%'`
- it's probably more interesting to compare `field3` and `field2` separately instead of comparing the *sum* of them.
- try to keep 'filters' as close to their table definition as possible. In this case I'd advice to put `sa.field6 <> 'EXPIRED'` next to the `JOIN sa` clause. This is optional, but if you'd ever need to `OUTER JOIN` it suddenly becomes a necessity!
- I'm also a bit wary about all the collation magic going on here... but maybe your data requires it...

Anyway, rewriting your code a bit, I come to this:

```
INSERT INTO This_Table 
SELECT DISTINCT * -- need ALL fields? Even then, better specify them explicitly!
  FROM fv
  JOIN lv 
    ON lv.field1 = fv.field1
  JOIN sa 
    ON sa.field1 = fv.field2
   AND sa.field6 <> 'EXPIRED'
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                    FROM fv fv22
                    JOIN lv lv2 
                      ON lv2.field1 = fv2.field1
                    JOIN This_Table T 
                      ON fv2.field2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
                                + (CASE WHEN COMPONENT_PART COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '[ST]%' 
                                            THEN STUFF(field3 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 1, 1, '')             
                                            ELSE COMPONENT_PART COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS END) 
                               LIKE T.field4 + (CASE WHEN field5 LIKE '[ST]%' 
                                                        THEN STUFF(field5, 1, 1, '') 
                                                        ELSE T.field5 END + '%')

                   WHERE fv2.field2 = fv.field2 -- not quite the same as what you had but I'm guessing this is what you wanted
                     AND fv2.field3 = fv.field3 )
```

Looking back on this, and assuming I didn't mess up, I'm now wondering if you really need the JOINs to `lv` in the first place?